# Calculating the work required to empty the fluid from the half torus

Tags: calculus

Below is the region bounded by the semi-circle centered at (3,0) with radius 2 and $y<0$

[image]

We rotate this region with respect to the y-axis and obtain half of a torus
[image]

Asssume that 3/4 of the torus is filled with the fluid and assume that the fluid has a mass density of $\rho$ kg/m^3. Set up but do not evaluate the integral that computes the work required to empty the fluid from the half torus (use g=9.8m/s^2)

The final answer is:

$-9.8\rho\pi\int_{-2}^{-1/2} y((3+\sqrt{4-y^2})-(3-\sqrt{4-y^2})^2)dy$

but I really don't understand how I would go about solving this problem.

This is what I know so far:

I need to find $\Delta V$ which is the volume of a typical slab.

Then I need to find the force required to lift the slab which is equal to its weight, so it's

$F=weight\Delta V$

Then I need to find the distance through with F needs to act to lift (which I'm assuming is $3/4y$ or something that has to do with the 3/4

Then the work to lift a slab is $\Delta W=force \times distance$

Then I need to integrate the above reimann sum.

I know how to do this process for other (probably easier) questions but for this problem I'm stuck because I've never done this for a torus. Can someone please show me how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with your first figure. Note that the semicircle intersects the $y$ axis at $(1,0)$ and $(5,0)$, not $4$ as shown. Now draw a slab of thickness $dy$ at a depth $y$ (this will be a value between $-2$ and $-1/2$). Find out where it intersects the semicircle (the $x$ coordinates). You use Pythagoras' theorem for that, knowing that the distance to the $(3,0)$ point is $2$:
$$y^2+(x-3)^2=2^2\\x=3\pm\sqrt{4-y^2}$$
The slab that you draw on figure one is a ring in 3D, with outer and inner radii given by the above formula, and height $dy$. You can calculate the volume, so you get the mass. You multiply with the gravitational acceleration, and you get the force. To get the work, you need to multiply with the distance. What distance? You need to get the fluid over the edge, so you need to get it from $y$ to $0$. Finally, you need to integrate over the $y$ coordinate.

Comment: why is the thickness between $-2$ and $-1/2$? how did you get those values?

Comment: The depth is between those values. You already have in the first figure $(3,-2)$ at the bottom of the torus, so the lowest point has $y=-2$ If the half torus would be full, the highest point would be $y=0$. But in your problem they tell you that it is $3/4$ full. So the height of the fluid inside the torus is $\frac34\cdot radius=\frac34\cdot 2=\frac32$. But this is measured from the lowest point, so the upper limit is $y=-2+\frac32=-\frac12$

Comment: ahhh that makes sense, thank you